# Calculating Greater Lower Bound (glb) reliability in Stata

Tags: stata, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I need to validate a couple of subscales in a larger questionnaire. Items in the scales range from 5 to 13 composed of dichotomous and ordinal values.

I currently use Cronbach's alpha to measure reliability of the scales. I read Sijtsma (2009) on the limitations of the Cronbach's alpha and want to include `glb` values as well.

Can anyone tell me how to calculate glb values in Stata?

Thank you in advance! :)